# Regular expression merge needed

Tags: regex

I need to check input against a specific pattern (xxxx.xx.xx)
e.g: 1234.12.34, 2.3.5, 22.22,1.0.3

I have made these rules

```
\d{0,4}
\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2}
\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}
```

is there a way to merge the 3 rules into one?
I thought of using the `?` operator nested into the later parts but I couldn't figure out the correct syntax
any pointers are appreciated
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:\d{0,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/aI4rA5/1

`|` or operator is what you need .

Comment: that was fast! Thanks a lot :) accepting in 10 minutes

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below,

```
^\d{0,4}(?:(?:\.\d{1,2})?\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aI4rA5/3)

`?` would turn the previous token as optional. And don't confuse `?` present in the non-capturing group.

`(?:...)` called [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) which will do matching only. It won't capture any characters. last `?` in this `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` pattern will turn the whole pattern, ie `(?:\.\d{1,2})` as optional.

`^` asserts that we are at the start and `$` asserts that we are at the end.

Comment: What does the `:` stand for?